# Parallel Programming and computing

Tags: parallel-processing

2. Suppose that there exists a magic square in which Sherlock Holmes copied the output of the reverse alphabetical string in a sequential manner. Later, he has given this magic square as an input to a parallel program running on a general-purpose parallel computer such that one of the characters from the first three rows gets erased due to some bug. With the help of underlying parallel capability-based hardware, the (parallel) program again arranges the modified output into the reverse alphabetical list (with the respect to the remaining 15 characters) such that the erased character is being pushed onto the last box of the magic square.

(a) Which is the methodology used by the parallel program. 
(b) Explain with the help of an example using the given reverse alphabetical string.

Comment: this oddly feel like an assignement. While interesting, i'm not sure it fits stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: It is assignment....I am trying to find some way forward to understand the background of the context under parallel programming.

Answer (score 0):

### A story about a pure-`[SERIAL]` Sherlock HOLMES
equipped with a magic-`[PARALLEL]`, yet <sub>( just a bit )</sub> "defective" WATSON ...

```
The initial state:

        anOrderedListOfCHARs   "abcdefghijklmnop"
        (indices)           :  ////////////////
                              0123456789ABCDEF

                              0    1    2    3
                               \    \    \    \     
        aMagicSQUARE:           [_]  [_]  [_]  [_]

                                [_]  [_]  [_]  [_]

                                [_]  [_]  [_]  [_]

                                [_]  [_]  [_]  [_]
                                   \    \    \    \
                                    C    D    E    F
```

---

Next ?

```
Sir Holmes, a "detective", has
                used [SERIAL]-process,
                putting one CHAR
                after another,
                in a reversed order,
                to produce this:

        aMagicSQUARE (indices)  [F]  [E]  [D]  [C]
                      reverse'd                         
                                [B]  [A]  [9]  [8]

                                [7]  [6]  [5]  [4]

                                [3]  [2]  [1]  [0]
```

---

Next ?

```
A [PARALLEL]-machine a "defective" one
                has damaged the
                state, somewhere
                in row 1, 2 or 3

                we do not know where
                we do yet know it was just one and only a one CHAR

        aMagicSQUARE (indices)   
                one & only one  [?]  [?]  [?]  [?]
                cell in R1:R3    
                has a single    [?]  [?]  [?]  [?]
                defect (EMPTY)   
                                [?]  [?]  [?]  [?]

                                [d]  [c]  [b]  [a]
```

---

Next ?

```
A [PARALLEL]-machine can first      ___________________________________
       [PARALLEL]-map cells        /    /    /    /                   /
                 back into      [F]  [E]  [D]  [C]                   /
                 a vector-like      ______________________________  /
                 list              /    /    /    /              / /
                                [B]  [A]  [9]  [8]              / /
                                    _________________________  / /
                                   /    /    /    /         / / /
                                [7]  [6]  [5]  [4]         / / /
                                    ____________________  / / /
                                   /    /    /    /    / / / /
                                [3]  [2]  [1]  [0]    / / / /
                                                     / / / /  
                                      0123__________/ / / /
                                     ////4567________/ / /
                                    ////////89AB______/ /
                                   ////////////CDEF____/
                                  ////////////////  
                                "abcdefghijklmnop"
                                ////////////////
                               0123456789ABCDEF
```

---

And now ?

```
Given the "defective" step,
           we expect not more
           than a one defect,
           so now we get this:
                                "????????????mnop"
                                ////////////////
                               0123456789ABCDEF
```

---

So ?

```
Next step is a [PARALLEL]-test
        for a single (empty)
        a one & only one
        index we can STORE
        it is a collision-free

           _aDefectCellINDEX_:      3  
                                    |
                                "abc^efghijklmnop"
                                ////////////////
                               0123456789ABCDEF
```

---

Next ?

```
Next step is a [PARALLEL]-shuffle
        for all cells
        since a single found defect
        it has to be orchestrated
        as a [PARALLEL]-READ,
        but a block/stride-safe
        ordered (as destructive)        ________________
        [PARALLEL]-WRITE               /               /
        for all cells "after"         3               /
        _aDefectCellINDEX_            ^456789ABCDEF  /
        and placing (EMPTY)          ^////////////  /
        "defect" to the last    "abc^efghijklmnop" /
        position in the list        ////////////  /
                               "abcefghijklmnop^"/
                                              /_/
```

---

```
Depending on the actual HARDWARE,
        the [PARALLEL]-machine
        may prefer to BLOCK-READ
                   to BLOCK-ERASE
                  and BLOCK-SHIFT/WRITE
        not to handle a single exception
                     (a defect) alone in a "divergent"-code-path
```

---

> *Elementary, dear Watson... Wasn't it?*